# Struggling to understand Random class constructor with one parameter of long type

Tags: java, random

I'm relatively new to java and is studying the random class in Java se8. I'm struggling to understand the random class constructor with one parameter of type long. I have attached a screen shot of the explanation in Java documentation, but I'm really struggling to understand what it actually means. Could someone please kindly explain it to me?

[image]

Comment: Well which bit of it don't you understand? Did you read the overview documentation which says a bit more about the seed?

Comment: Wikipedia has a pretty nice definition of what a "seed" is in programming algorithms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pseudorandom number generator does not actually create random numbers. Instead, it has an internal state and performs a calculation on it that produces a seemingly random number and updates the internal state (so that you get a different number the next time you ask the generator for one).

The sequence of numbers in completely determined by the internal state. In this case, it is a `long` (for cryptographically strong PRNG it will be something bigger). For the same `long` seed, you will get the same sequence of numbers back.

You might want to do that in order to reproduce a previous sequence exactly. If you don't care, you can leave the seed unspecified (in this case some default will be supplied that is different every time).